# Как получить перенаправяемую ссылку

Tags: php

В твиттере ссылки имеют такой вид https://t.co/Lh2VMRvfqq. 
Как в php получить ссылку, на которую ведет эта ссылка?

Comment: Чем получить? Если через curl то думаю если включить CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION то можно получить оригинальную ссылку.

Comment: а если file_get_contents?

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите это сделать с помощью функции [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php) то нужно указать параметры в контексте чтобы не было перенаправления, получить headers и найти нужный вам.

Сначала получим всем headers:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'follow_location' => false
        )
    )
);

file_get_contents('https://t.co/Sgw7gx9XUv', false, $context);
```

В итоге мы получим в зарезервированную переменную [$http_response_header](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) все headers.

Дальше проходимся по ним и находим тот что нам нужен:

```
$url = null;
foreach ($http_response_header as $header) {
    if (strpos($header, 'location: ') === false) {
        continue;
    }
    $url = substr($header, strpos($header, 'http'));
}
echo $url;
```

В итоге в переменной `$url` и будет оригинальный путь.